# echo value from 1 input box into another with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textinput

I have an AJAX powered form which is more like a 5 step wizard. There are no page refreshes until the data is submitted at the very end.

On an earlier step a value is entered into a HTML  text field and I would like to have those same values present in another text box on the last page as they review the final details of their submission before they hit send..

I think it needs to be done with an onChange event but I cannot seem to get it to work fully, I am a PHP developer so am still working on my jQuery skills. Here is the code I wrote with no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#textbox1").change(function()
        {
    var text = $("#textbox1").val(); 
    $("#textbox2").html(text);
        }); 
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance gents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.val` is used for both getting and setting a input's value:

- `.val()` returns the value
- `.val(something)` sets the value

So:

```
$("#textbox2").val(text);
```

---

`.html` is used to get/set an element's HTML contents, but for input elements that does not make sense. The following is bogus (which is what `.html` is trying):

```
<input>some html</input>
```

Comment: That is perfect, thanks for the clear explanation on how to use .val ! Thanks again for your expertise

Answer (score 7):

You're almost there.  You just need to use `val` method to set the value, and not `html` method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#textbox1").change(function()
        {
    var text = $("#textbox1").val(); 
    $("#textbox2").val(text);
        }); 
});
</script>
```